# Implement slightly different kernel smoothing density in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've been trying to implement this equation into matlab:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/46747/Capture.PNG

Omega is some known region of the image `u1`.

and `p1,i` is:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/46748/Capture1.PNG

Pay attention: `u1` is an image (column ordered), an `p1,i` is supposed to be calculated in each pixel of this image.

Now, I've calculated `p1,i` in this way:

```
[f1,xi1] = ksdensity(u1(:),1:255);
p1_u1 = reshape(f1(floor(u1(:))+1),M,N);
```

Now my problem is to calculate the former equation.

I've tried with `for` loop but its taking forever..

Any other suggestions? Maybe there's a way using `ksdensity` and change the value inside the integral?

Thanks!

Comment: Neither of those images show for me. It just shows as garbled text (?) If you edit your post you can just include those images in your post by clicking the "image" icon.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/46747/Capture.PNG

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/46748/Capture1.PNG

Comment: These are links to the images, although i see them fine